# Why using .clone() this way still gets the same address with the original object?

Tags: java, arraylist

The code is:

```
public static void mergeShelves(Scanner scanner, ArrayList<ArrayList<Bookset>> shelves){
        String excepInfo = "Oh, no. We fail!";
        int i = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        int j = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        ArrayList<Bookset> tem1 = (ArrayList<Bookset>)(shelves.get(i).clone());
        System.out.println(tem1);
        System.out.println(shelves.get(i);
        ...
}
```

And *stdout*:

```
[Computer@3941a79c]
[Computer@3941a79c]
```

I can't see any problems. The omitted part is not essential to this problem as far as I'm considering.

And `Bookset` here is a public class defined previously, FYI, it contains books' information.

Consider an `ArrayList<Bookset>` as a bookshelf, certainly an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Bookset>>` is a bunch of bookshelves.

Comment: Dunno.  Maybe `clone()` is not properly implemented?  Show the code.

Comment: Because `ArrayList.clone()` does a shallow copy, so it won't create any new `Bookset` objects (or `Computer` objects, your code and output don't seem to be related).

Answer (score 0):

[`ArrayList::clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()) does a shallow copy of what it contains.

That means the two `ArrayList` you're comparing (`tem1` and `shelves.get(i)`) actually contain the same object(s) which is what is getting printed.

Comment: This makes sense. But I'm a tyro and I just wonder what to do to get what I want which is to create a new `ArrayList` and everything is the same but address. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean you want to do a deep copy which also clones the elements in the list?